# Extract part of string in SQL that is between two character but there are multiple of same characters

Tags: sql, substring, varchar, charindex

I'm trying to extract part of a string that is between two characters, the string looks like -

EXAMPLE/EXMPL/BBASIC/***EXAMPLE***/EXAMPLE

The text I am trying to move to a separate column is the 4th section of text between the 3rd and 4th '/' (in bold)

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: `split_part(the_column, '/', 4)`

Comment: The correct answer is RDBMS specific. Answering this question without knowing what RDBMS to use is pure guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the DBMS, I'm not sure if there is a built-in split function or not.  SQL Server 2008 R2 does not have a split function, so I do it this way:

```
declare @str varchar(max) = 'example/example/bbasic/eXaMpLe/example', @delim char(1) = '/'

;with vars(id, _start, _end) as
(
  select 1, cast(1 as bigint), charindex(@delim, @str)

  union all

  select id + 1, _end + 1, charindex(@delim, @str, _end + 1)
  from   vars
  where  _end > 0
)
select id, cast(substring(@str, _start, case when _end > 0 then _end - _start else len(@str) - _start + 1 end) as varchar(max)) as value
from   vars
where  id = 4
option (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Using `where id = 4` means pull the 4th element after the 3rd `/` delimiter.  This SQL returns:

```
id  value
--- --------
4   eXaMpLe
```